# Configuration in aerospike to notify before memory is full

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, aerospike

I have installed an aerospike instance on ubuntu server 16.04. I want to get notified before aerospike memory alloted for a namespace reaches to it's limit. Is there any configuration available in aerospike? If not, can anyone please suggest me an alternative for it?

Comment: There are differenthttps://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/?show-removed=1#system_free_mem_pct

Comment: There are different stats one can monitor: System Memory Free: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/?show-removed=1#system_free_mem_pct and memory free on the namespace itself: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/?show-removed=1#memory_free_pct

Answer (score 3):

Aerospike provides a bunch of plugins to pump data into external monitoring systems which are capable of alerting. You can use the one that is appropriate for you. Refer to the list : https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/monitor/